# visual studio 2012 web performance test , getting Validation of viewstate MAC failed error in post requests

Tags: performance, validation, testing, web, viewstate

when using web performance test in visual studio 2012 it results the following error after running the test for post requests only:

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was resolved I disabled enableEventValidation, enableViewStateMac from web.config